# To read a zipped (csv) file downloaded in a temp file

Tags: r, csv, zip

I was trying code given by Dirk to download and read a zipped csv file from a website. The code :

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/Economic_Fitness_CSV.zip" ,temp)
```

I can see that the file is being read into a temp file.

temp

```
C:\\Users\\DCC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpu61Cca\\file27346fd263d0
```

However, I am getting an error when I run the following code

```
data <- read.csv(unz(temp, "Economic_Fitness_CSV.zip"))
unlink(temp)
```

> Warning message in unzip(temp, "C:/Users/DCC/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpu61Cca/Economic_Fitness_CSV.csv"):
>   "error 1 in extracting from zip file"
>   Error: 'Economic_Fitness_CSV.csv' does not exist in current working directory ('D:/MADS/02 DATA422_Data Wrangling/LABs/Lab 1').
>   Traceback:

I don't understand this error - how is 'Economic_Fitness_CSV.csv' supposed to exist in my working directory before it has been extracted / copied from the temp file ?

Maybe, I am missing out a simple point - but have not been able to resolve this on my own.

Comment: Try the path `"http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/Economic_Fitness_CSV.zip"` , and see the contents of the zip with `unzip(temp, list = TRUE)`  -- it shows three csv's for me

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't try `read.csv(unz(temp))`? Not only is the directory you used different (I suggest you read about *working directory*, ala `getwd` and `setwd`), but the filename itself is different too (`file27346fd263d0` versus `Economic_Fitness_CSV.zip`).

Comment: Looks like the name is not what you expected. You should use your system utilities to see what is in that directory.